# Making ChrootDirectory directory writable by SFTP user

Tags: ssh, sftp, openssh

If a user logs into a machine via SFTP, one can make use of `ChrootDirectory` keyword to give an illusion that user is in a root directory. But that directory is only writable by `root` user. I would love for this user to have such write capabilities, and it doesn't appear that OpenSSH offers this, unless I missed something?

I am aware that that SFTP user can be given write access to any file/directory inside that `ChrootDirectory`, but it's not good enough. I want the user to also create/delete the files directly under that "root" directory, without the workaround of creating a subdirectory that that user has write access to.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with my in-house SFTP. What I did to get around this is:

Inside your **sshd_config** file:

```
Match group     sftpusers
  ChrootDirectory %h
```

Inside your **/etc/groups** file, add your sftp user to the `sftpusers` group (create it if it doesn't exist):

```
sftpusers:x:6000:user1,user2
```

For the ChrootDirectory, make sure you `chown` the directory to the following *(warning be-careful of the directory that you are running this command on, make sure it is being run only on the directory that the user logs into, the `-R` commend means recursive, so if there are subfolder you do not wish this to command to include, remove it. Also a SFTP user should never be given access to a root level system directory like `/etc`, best to make a folder under something like `/usr/local/alcatraz` and give them access to that)*:

```
chown -R root:sftpusers userChrootDirectory
```

Chmod the directory to have the permission you desire, something like:

```
drwxrws---
```

If you require more information, let me know, this is just the highlights, that should get you to where you want to be.

Comment: For openssh this method (adding group write permissions to the chroot directory) will not work. Quoted from the openssh (at least version 7.2) `sshd_config(5)` man page: "At session startup sshd(8) checks that all components of the pathname are root-owned directories which are not writable by any other user or group."

Comment: `ChrootDirectory %h` suggests you want to use the user's (e.g. `user1`'s) home directory (e.g. `/home/user1`) as chroot target, but that's not possible because that directory is owned by the user (e.g. `user1`) whereas the OpenSSH requirement is that it must be owned by root. Also, you cannot make it writeable by giving group write permissions because OpenSSH also does not allow that.